# Error while editing a Search Box Web Part in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, edit, search-box

We've added a Search Box web part on a page. After editing the page, when a user tries to edit the Search Box web part, it gives him error "Sorry, Something went wrong". He has 'Design' permission on the site and page. This error happens only for this particular user but for his colleague who has same permission as this user, is able to edit the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the masterpage gallery and check the permissions for the library. The permissions shouldn't be inherited and the user should have "read"-permission. As default the "all authentificated user"-Group have read-permission to this library. I got the same error as you and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, user didn't had permission on masterpage gallery. The issue was resolved after giving permission there. Had figured this out a long time ago but thanks anyway for answering. Marking your answer as correct one!